# upload videos to s3 via API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to upload mp4 videos to a s3 bucket via an API Gateway but I don't know how to do that. Everything works fine when I send a pdf file with **Content-Type:application/pdf** using this lambda function:

```
import json
import base64
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    
    get_file_content = event["content"]
    decode_content = base64.b64decode(get_file_content)
    
    s3_upload = s3.put_object(Bucket="mybucket", Key="content.pdf", Body=decode_content)
    
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

but how can I upload mp4 videos ???
Many thanks for your help

Comment: How big are those videos?

Comment: Are you asking what content type to use, or are you saying that you've tried but it has failed? More information, please.

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem with MP4 files?

Comment: @Marcin: 30-50 sec

Comment: I tried to upload mp4 videos and it worked. I followed this tutorial: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETb2eVJs5UE&list=PLdN_HXjvSx3dzX3yqCoUoRLOI5eTPL5bY&index=7) But what I don't understand is that everyone advises to use presigned urls. Do I need to use presigned urls ???